# Boolean condition not working properly in do-while loop

Tags: c++, boolean, do-while

The loop in the function require() takes 3 conditions, a > b or "a" or "b" aren't digits. Even when I don't satisfy the conditions and put 2 integers in, it just loops once again.

Also when I put in a character then it just endlessly loops "Enter minimum number Enter maximum number" ignoring the cins. Anyone know why? I'm a beginner so this is probably really obvious

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int random(int minN, int maxN)   //generates random number within specified range
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int x = (maxN - minN);
    int y = minN + (rand() % (x+1));
    return y;
}

int require()        //makes sure a < b and both are digits
{
    int a,b;
    do {
    cout << "Enter minimum number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter maximum number. Note: Has to be greater or equal to minimum." << endl;
    cin >> b;
    } while (a > b || !isdigit(a) || !isdigit(b));

    return random(a,b);
}

int main()
{
    cout << require() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Sorry fixed my wording

Comment: `isdigit` is for testing characters. If you pass it integers as arguments, it interprets them as character under a certain encoding (depending on locale).

Comment: Also, what do you mean _even when I satisfy the conditions, [...] it loops again_. That's how a do-while loop works: It loops _as long as_ the condition is satisfied. It stops when the condition is no longer satisfied.

Comment: Sorry fixed that too, is there a function that interprets numbers instead of characters?

Comment: What exactly do you want the function to check? An ordinary integer is a digit (in the decimal system) if it is `>= 0` and `< 10`.

Comment: You only need to call `srand (time(NULL));` once at the start of the program.

Comment: I want to make sure that the inputs are integers and not characters

Comment: `std::cin >> a;` when `a` is an `int` is not the best way to accept input, IMHO. Taking input as a `string` allows for virtually blow-up-free input. Then you'd actually be able to use those convenient  functions you're calling while avoiding unexptected behaviour. There is no way to guarantee your user will not provide a `?` for an `int` or accidentally hold a key down and exceed your `int`. It's either that or get up on your exception handling skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `isdigit` as this relates to a particular character is a digiti. Instead the loop should look like this:

```
int require()        //makes sure a < b and both are digits
{
    validNumbers = true;
    do
    {
       cout << "Enter minimum number" << endl;
       cin.clear();
       cin >> a;
    } while (cin.fail());

    do
    {
       cout << "Enter maximum number. Note: Has to be greater or equal to minimum."
            << endl;
       cin.clear();
       cin >> b;
    } while (cin.fail() || a > b);

    return random(a,b);
}
```

**PS:** You only need to call `srand (time(NULL));` once at the start of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the numbers as, well, numbers not as characters as the `isdigit` function expects. If you are using a C++11 compliant standard library, the values of `a` and `b` will actually be zero if the input is not valid integer numbers, which means that e.g. `!isdigit(a)` will be `true`. If you are using a non-C++11 library, then the value of `a` and `b` will be random, and will most likely cause `!isdigit(a)` to be true as well as the amount of valid digit ASCII values in a full 32-bit integer range is quite small.

---

If you read a reference about the input operator, like [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) you will see that if extraction fails, then the streams `failbit` will be set. This can either be tested "inline" like this:

```
if (!(std::cin >> a))
{
    std::cout << "Not a valid number, try again: ";
    continue;
}
```

Or it can be tested using the streams [`fail`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) function.

Comment: I see, what can I do instead? I'm not too knowledgeable but would something like atoi work?

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was stupid for not figuring this out, but I just haven't learned enough syntax